# Push app package using REST API

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I have installed a standalone cluster on my server. I see almost all of the commands are supported by tools but can't find a way to push an app package using the REST API.
Is that possible?

Comment: What do you mean by "way to push an app package"? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/servicefabric/sfclient-api-createapplication

Comment: I mean uploading the app package to image store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using `sfctl` CLI to manage the cluster. It uses HTTP connection.

From the docs, I found that [Upload File](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/servicefabric/sfclient-api-uploadfile) could be used to upload the app package to image store.

Answer (score 1):

`sfctl application upload` command may be a better option for uploading an application to the image store in the selected cluster.

```
sfctl application upload --path path-to-directory-with-ApplicationManifest.xml --show-progress
```